# Typescript property decorator auto-add to prototype

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I'd like to create a decoration for properties that will allow me to automatically add the property without the need to write it into the constructor. I'm fairly new to Java/Type script so hopefully I didn't butcher this too bad. I can't seem to do this, here's what I have so far...

The goal is that with something along the lines of:

```
class A {
  @uuid
  'property': string;
  'another': string;
}

function uuid(target: any, key: string): void {
  Reflect.defineMetadata('isUuid', true, target, key);
}
```

I'd be able to later use `A`'s constructor `new () => Object` to get a list of all the properties and whether or not they're UUIDs. I assume this would look something like:

```
Object.keys(A).forEach(key => {
  console.log(`[${key}].isUuid? ${Reflect.getMetadata('isUuid', A, key) === true}`);
});
```

Which would hopefully yield something like:

```
[property].isUuid? true
[another].isUuid? false
```

As a note, If I change class `A` to:

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.property = undefined;
    this.another = undefined;
  }
  @uuid
  'property': string;
  'another': string;
}
```

I can get this to work, but I have to create an instance of `A` to be able to get the keys and get the metadata on those.

Comment: why do you need the non-uuid properties?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is use decorators to add extra criteria to the property. This will eventually be used as a model for a database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to access every property, you will need to decorate every property.  Since the `reflect-metadata` API doesn't let you enumerate the `targetKey`s used on an object, you should store the metadata on the object itself.

First, define what kind of information you want to note for each property.  So far, there's `isUuid`:

```
interface DbPropInfo {
  isUuid: boolean; 
  // other stuff
}
```

It helps to have a default value for each piece of information so the decorator annotations can be concise:

```
const defaultDbPropInfo: DbPropInfo = {
  isUuid: false 
}
```

We will want to store the metadata as an object whose keys are the same as the property keys of the class, and whose values are the `DbPropInfo` we set for those properties.  Here's a type for that object:

```
interface DbProps {
  [k: string]: DbPropInfo;
}
```

And now for the decorator:

```
const dbPropsKey = 'dbProps';

function dbProp(info?: Partial<DbPropInfo>) {
  return function(target: any, key: string): void {
    if (!Reflect.hasMetadata(dbPropsKey, target)) {
      Reflect.defineMetadata(dbPropsKey, {}, target);
    }
    const dbProps: DbProps = Reflect.getMetadata(dbPropsKey, target);
    dbProps[key] = Object.assign({}, defaultDbPropInfo, info);
  }
}
```

And to get the decorated data:

```
function getDbProps(ctor: { prototype: any }): DbProps | undefined {
  return Reflect.getMetadata(dbPropsKey, ctor.prototype);
}
```

---

Finally we can try it on your class:

```
class A {
  @dbProp({ isUuid: true }) property: string;
  @dbProp() another: string;
}
```

Let's see if it works:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(getDbProps(A)));
// { 
//   "property": {"isUuid": true},
//   "another": {"isUuid": false}
// }
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Interesting, that's a great idea. I ended up (last night) finding a way to inject the property by first checking if the `key` was in `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target)` then adding it using `Object.defineProperty(target, key, ...)` But I think your way makes more sense.